# Play! framework instance as view/controller layer and others for REST services layer

Tags: api, web-applications, playframework-2.0

I'm about to create a new imposing web project using Play! framework (similar to Rails philosophy).

After reading some important parts of this famous book: [Service-Oriented Design with Ruby and Rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321659368) for learning some tips on good design, I wish to avoid monolithic application by creating separated Play! applications as services layers (through REST).

Thus, I imagine the first Play! application would be responsible for routing clients' requests to remote services layers contained each one in other Play! applications.

I wonder both things with this solution:

- Where to put Entities/Values Objects (data model)? May there be some kind of data-model.jar shared between view application and services applications? (Optional for view since DTO's or JSON object would be sufficient)
- View application would end up with no model layer, since view application acts as a simple proxy for services applications. Doesn't it promote confusion or potential bad understanding for future developers (an application with view/controller but without model part)? Likewise, services applications wouldn't contain view layer...

In short, each of these applications using Play! would seem to follow this bad principle: **YAGNI**